# 3D Plot of Multiple Time Series in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization, timeserieschart

I've seen numerous examples of 3D plots using matplotlib/seaborn in Python but can't seem to get what I'm looking for; I have 50 or so timeseries that I would like to plot cleanly as in the following example below but with the name of the series on the axis; as an example I've marked in Goog, IBM, GE, Pepsi etc. Appreciate any pointers or examples. Thank you,

[Example PLOT Click Here Please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjYTq.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Matplotlib` has very rich gallery. I found [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/gallery/animation/unchained.html#sphx-glr-gallery-animation-unchained-py), you can only plot it once instead of animation. And manually put y-axis [legend](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yticks.html) wherever you want.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)


# Create new Figure with black background
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))

# Add a subplot with no frame
ax = plt.subplot(111, frameon=False)

# Generate random data
data = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (64, 75))
X = np.linspace(-1, 1, data.shape[-1])
G = 1.5 * np.exp(-4 * X ** 2)

# Generate line plots
lines = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    # Small reduction of the X extents to get a cheap perspective effect
    xscale = 1 - i / 200.
    # Same for linewidth (thicker strokes on bottom)
    lw = 1.5 - i / 100.0
    line, = ax.plot(xscale * X, i + G * data[i], color="b", lw=lw)
    lines.append(line)

# Set y limit (or first line is cropped because of thickness)
ax.set_ylim(-1, 70)

# No ticks
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])

# 2 part titles to get different font weights
ax.text(0.5, 1.0, "MATPLOTLIB ", transform=ax.transAxes,
        ha="right", va="bottom", color="k",
        family="sans-serif", fontweight="light", fontsize=16)
ax.text(0.5, 1.0, "UNCHAINED", transform=ax.transAxes,
        ha="left", va="bottom", color="k",
        family="sans-serif", fontweight="bold", fontsize=16)


def update(*args):
    # Shift all data to the right
    data[:, 1:] = data[:, :-1]

    # Fill-in new values
    data[:, 0] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, len(data))

    # Update data
    for i in range(len(data)):
        lines[i].set_ydata(i + G * data[i])

    # Return modified artists
    return lines

# Construct the animation, using the update function as the animation director.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Jay- this is fantastic. Thank you Any clue how you can add y-axis labels for say every 3rd series?

Comment: .. and a way to display datetimes on the x-axis would be cool .. ill try and figure this out but thank you for this link